# How to create a child record after create the parent in a single transaction (Rails 5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to create a User and an Employee in a single transaction, i couldn't find a proper way to do it.

Here are the models.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :employee
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and in the controller i receive the params from the request to create both models.

```
{
    "username": "my_user",
    "password": "12345",
    "employee": {
        "name: "my_name",
        "lastname": "my_lastname"
    }
}
```

So i would like to do something like this.

```
class UsersController < ResourcesController
    def create
        user = User.create! do |u|
           u.username = params.username
           u.password = params.password
        end
        employee = Employee.create! do |e|
           e.name = params.name
           e.lastname = params.lastname
           e.user_id = user.id
        end
    end
end
```

The problem here, is that if an exception is thrown after the user is created, then the database would be inconsistent.
How can i do it properly and safety?

Well, I've been banging my head against this brick wall for quite some time. Any help to shed some light on this will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just curious why two different models for user and employee, mostly each employee has one username

Comment: because the user can exist without the employee and if an employee exists, it must have a user. So when i create the Employee, the user must be created first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :employee inverse_of :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user inverse_of :employee
  validates_presence_of :user
end

class UsersController < ResourcesController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save!
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, employee_attributes: [:name,:last_name])
  end
end
```